# Exporting to CSV, Non Sequential Columns from a Table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA macro to export the content of table to a csv file. I would like to include only certain columns and ignore all other ones. My code works fine for a single column (in the case below, `col_a`), but it fails when trying to export multiple columns (e.g. `col_a` and `col_c`).

```
Sub saveTableToCSV()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim csvFilePath As String
    Dim fNum As Integer
    Dim tblArr
    Dim rowArr
    Dim csvVal

    Set tbl = Worksheets("primary").ListObjects("main")
    csvFilePath = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\testsheet.csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    tblArr = Range("main[[col_a]]").Value

    fNum = FreeFile()
    Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum
    For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
        rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
        csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ",")
        Print #1, csvVal
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Close #fNum
    Set tblArr = Nothing
    Set rowArr = Nothing
    Set csvVal = Nothing
End Sub
```

An example of my data would be below. The table name is "main" and the sheet name is "primary":

```
-------------------------
| col_a | col_b | col_c |
-------------------------
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
-------------------------
```

My desired output would be a csv file that looks like the following:

```
a,c
1,3
4,6
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your code only refers to column `col_a`, not column `col_c`.  Try setting `tblArr` to be the whole table, and make the `rowArr = ` line in the for-loop be a bit more complicated, picking and choosing only the columns you want.  Maybe `rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0) + Application.Index(tblArr, i, 2)`? (after you've set `tblArr` to be the whole table, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace that line

```
tblArr = Range("main[[col_a]]").Value
```

with these two lines

```
    tblArr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
    tblArr = Application.Index(tblArr, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & UBound(tblArr) & ")"), [{1,3}])
```

Comment: I think you'll need to tweak the `rowArr = ` line later on, too.

Comment: Worked great. Is there anyway to alter that so I can reference a particular header field values (col_a and col_c) rather than the column number (1,3) ?

Comment: May be using Application.Match to find the desired header then store that number in a variable and use it. I think it is easier to determine the column numbers